# What's the difference between "creek", "brook", "run", and "river"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between these names of moving water?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31471/whats-the-difference-between-these-names-of-moving-water)

What's the difference between *creek*, *brook*, *run*, and *river*?   I need to name a small river in my novel and was thinking about what are the difference between these words.

Comment: Generally speaking, all the first three just mean ***small** river*, but I think *run* is relatively uncommon/dialectal. Probably just a personal interpretation, but I tend to think of a *creek* as a small watercourse that over time has carved a lower bed than a brook/stream. Not that the water itself is deep - just that its surface is often significantly lower than surrounding ground level.

Comment: Not _beck_ or _burn_, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jay Elston wrote in reply to the question "[What's the difference between these names of moving water?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31471)",

> Generally, the difference is size: you can step over a brook, jump over a creek, wade across a stream, and swim across a river. But the distinction between them (especially creek and stream) is somewhat hazy, and depends on who named them and when they were named. A run (such as Bull Run in Virginia) is a "small stream".

I agree with the ranking in that previous answer, but not with the criteria, which are not conclusive because many exceptions exist.